# Express js Image upload and Text inputs using post method

Tags: node.js, express

**I have following code for uploading image and handling text input. But both are not working together** 
*Images are uploading properly but I can't get text field value *

```js
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var mime    =   require('mime');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.' + mime.extension(file.mimetype));
  }
});
var upload = multer({ storage : storage }).array('userPic');

app.get('/completeForm.html', function(req, res){
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/' + 'completeForm.html')
});

app.post("/postFormAct", function (req, res, next) {
 console.log(req.body.user); // Here i getting undefined
 console.log(req.body.email);// Here i getting undefined
 
 upload(req,res,function(err) {
  console.log(req.files); // Here i getting proper output and image also uploading to concern folder
 });
 
});

app.listen(3000);
```

*Html code given below.... please help me someone*

```html
<form method="post" action="/postFormAct" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="user"><br>
    <input type="text" name="email"><br>
 <input type="file" name="userPic"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put

```
console.log(req.body.user);
console.log(req.body.email);
```

inside your upload function. After the function may also work.

Answer (score 0):

That's because there is no `multipart/form-data` parsing middleware called before your `/postFormAct` route handler.

You have two parsing middlewares set up but not one of them parse this `multipart/form-data` Content-Type.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Multer does that, so you can access `req.body.user` and `req.body.email` variables in handlers following your `upload` middleware.